# Highlighting selected item in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react project that uses a dynamically created menu in material ui, like this:

```
const createDays = (selectedDay, defaultStyles, selectedStyles) => {

  const days = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const day = createDate(i);
    days.push(<MenuItem selected={day.dayOfTheWeek === selectedDay.dayOfTheWeek} classes={{ root: defaultStyles, selected: selectedStyles }} key={i} value={day}>{day.dayOfTheWeek}</MenuItem>);
  }
  return days;
};
```

this method is referred to here:

```
const DayPickerContainer = ({ day, onChange, classes }) => {
  const menuItemStyles = classes.menuItem;
  const select = classes.selected1;
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormHelperText className={classes.helperText}>Choose Day</FormHelperText>
      <Select value={day} onChange={onChange}>
        <MenuItem value={day}>{day.dayOfTheWeek}</MenuItem>
        {createDays(day, menuItemStyles, select)}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>

  );
};
```

And these are the styles used:

```
const styles = () => ({
  helperText: {
    fontSize: '23px',
  },

  menuItem: {
    fontSize: '20px',
    backgroundColor: 'white !important',
  },

  selected: {
    backgroundColor: 'red !important',
  },

});
```

When an item is selected in the menu, I want that item to then have a different background color to the other items.  However at the moment nothing changes when a different item is selected.